# as.POSIX error, can not convert a particular date

Tags: r

When I'm debugging my r codes, I found an error hard to explain. Does anyone know what's going on?

When I try `as.POSIXct("1940-06-01")` or `as.POSIXlt("1940-06-01")`, I always get

```r
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

However, when I try other dates, there's no error.

```r
> as.POSIXlt("1940-06-25")
[1] "1940-06-25 CDT"
> as.POSIXlt("1940-06-03")
[1] "1940-06-25 CDT"
```

Actually, if I add one more argument, there's no error.

```r
> as.POSIXlt("1940-06-01",tz="GMT")
[1] "1940-06-01 GMT"
> as.POSIXct("1940-06-01",tz="GMT")
[1] "1940-06-01 GMT"
```

I just wonder why R hates this particular date so much?

Comment: daylight saving shenanigans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@HongOoi is right, "daylight saving shenanigans". Midnight on June 1, 1940, just did not exist in some time zones.

Ultimately, since `"1940-06-01"` is interpreted by the `as.POSIX*` functions as `"1940-06-01 00:00:00"` in the particular time zone, we can say that ***that time did not exist*** (according to the tzdata time zone database).

I just tried this with all 562 of the time zones included in `OlsonNames()`, and it fails for 10 of them:

```r
str(lapply(head(OlsonNames(),3),
           function(tz) as.POSIXlt("1940-06-01", tz = tz)))
# List of 3
#  $ : POSIXlt[1:1], format: "1940-06-01"
#  $ : POSIXlt[1:1], format: "1940-06-01"
#  $ : POSIXlt[1:1], format: "1940-06-01"

### this time through, if it works return "", if it errors return the tz instead
tzoops <- lapply(OlsonNames(), function(tz) tryCatch({
  ignore <- as.POSIXlt("1940-06-01", tz = tz)
  ""
}, error = function(e) tz))

### "" indicates no error occurred
head(tzoops, 2)
# [[1]]
# [1] ""
# [[2]]
# [1] ""

### these zones failed for some reason
unlist(Filter(nzchar, tzoops))
#  [1] "Asia/Chongqing" "Asia/Chungking" "Asia/Gaza"      "Asia/Harbin"    "Asia/Hebron"   
#  [6] "Asia/Jerusalem" "Asia/Shanghai"  "Asia/Tel_Aviv"  "Israel"         "PRC"
```

I'll pick one randomly: Israel, and do a little research at timeanddate.com for Isreal (see note 1 below), where it says that up through 1939, Israel's time zone has

> No changes, UTC +2 hours all of the period

but in 1940, `Sat, Jun 1 at 12:00 am` marks the daylight-savings change from IST to IDT. (And then in 1941 Israel shifted to UTC+3, not relevant for this dilemma.)

With this, we can determine that `1940-05-31 23:59:59` existed, but one second later it shifted an hour for DST:

```r
as.POSIXct("1940-05-31 23:59:59 PST", tz = "Israel")
# [1] "1940-05-31 23:59:59 IST"
as.POSIXct("1940-05-31 23:59:59 PST", tz = "Israel") + 1 # one second later
# [1] "1940-06-01 01:00:00 IDT"
```

We can verify similar results for all of the other time zones by parsing one second *before* midnight and then adding 1 second. (I've added "UTC" at the top to show what I would expect to happen if we were not dealing with a DST issue.)

```r
str(lapply(setNames(nm = c("UTC", unlist(Filter(nzchar, tzoops)))),
           function(tz) as.POSIXct("1940-05-31 23:59:59 PST", tz = tz) + c(0, 1)))
# List of 11
#  $ UTC           : POSIXct[1:2], format: "1940-05-31 23:59:59" "1940-06-01 00:00:00"
#  $ Asia/Chongqing: POSIXct[1:2], format: "1940-05-31 23:59:59" "1940-06-01 01:00:00"
#  $ Asia/Chungking: POSIXct[1:2], format: "1940-05-31 23:59:59" "1940-06-01 01:00:00"
#  $ Asia/Gaza     : POSIXct[1:2], format: "1940-05-31 23:59:59" "1940-06-01 01:00:00"
#  $ Asia/Harbin   : POSIXct[1:2], format: "1940-05-31 23:59:59" "1940-06-01 01:00:00"
#  $ Asia/Hebron   : POSIXct[1:2], format: "1940-05-31 23:59:59" "1940-06-01 01:00:00"
#  $ Asia/Jerusalem: POSIXct[1:2], format: "1940-05-31 23:59:59" "1940-06-01 01:00:00"
#  $ Asia/Shanghai : POSIXct[1:2], format: "1940-05-31 23:59:59" "1940-06-01 01:00:00"
#  $ Asia/Tel_Aviv : POSIXct[1:2], format: "1940-05-31 23:59:59" "1940-06-01 01:00:00"
#  $ Israel        : POSIXct[1:2], format: "1940-05-31 23:59:59" "1940-06-01 01:00:00"
#  $ PRC           : POSIXct[1:2], format: "1940-05-31 23:59:59" "1940-06-01 01:00:00"
```

So lacking further detailed research on each one of those time zones, my guess is that they have similar changes on that day.

---

Notes:

1. https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/israel/jerusalem?year=1940

   [image: timeanddate.com table screenshot, just in case]

Comment: Wow, amazing! It's really helpful. Thank you so much for your work.